# Scheme Explanation

Tags: scheme

I am reading a programming languages book and it is asking me to to explain what the following Scheme function does (not sure, can someone help explain):

```
(define (x lis)
  (cond ((null? lis) 0) 
        ((not (list? (car lis))) 
         (cond 
          ((eq? (car lis) #f) (x (cdr lis))) 
          (else (+ 1 (x (cdr lis)))))) 
        (else (+ (x (car lis)) (x (cdr lis))))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It counts the number of leaf nodes a nested list structure, ignoring `#f`. It uses a recursive procedure:

- If the input is an empty list, this is the base case that returns 0.
- If the input is a pair whose `car` is not a list:

  - If the `car` is `#f`, we recurse on the `cdr` and return that.
  - Otherwise we count the `car` as 1, and add that to the result of recursing on the `cdr`.
- Finally, we recurse on both the `car` and `cdr`, and add them together.

Comment: If I want to convert it into the programming language clojure how would I do it?

Comment: Don't you think you'll learn more by trying it yourself? If you have a problem, post a new question and we'll help you understand where you went wrong.

Comment: @user1585656: Clojure is a lisp language like Scheme, so it wouldn't take that much work to convert it.  It's straight-forward enough that you should be able to do it by looking up the functions in Scheme and finding Clojure equivalents.  If you're stuck on something specific then, just ask here, but you'll get a lot more help if you give it a shot first and show what you did.  If people believe you did your part, many will go far to help you out.